# Paste formula every four columns, adding four to column reference

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the following four formulas and paste it in the adjacent four columns with the column reference changing by four everytime.  What i mean is copy F4:I4 and paste to J4:M4,N4:Q4...with the "F" cahnging to a "J", then "N", then "Q" and so on until the end of the columns in the sheet.

```
=IF(AND(F2>=$C$4,F2<=$D$4),TRUE, FALSE)
=IF(AND((F2+6)>=$C$4,(F2+6)<=$D$4),TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(AND((F2+12)>=$C$4,(F2+12)<=$D$4),TRUE,FALSE)
=IF(AND((F2+18)>=$C$4,(F2+18)<=$D$4),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Am I able to some way loop this going across each column, and after the fourth add four to the numerical value of the cell reference? so instead of F2 and J2 I have Col_ID, Col_ID+4...Not sure how to write this in VBA.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I used this to merge every four cells above to make the "labels", i'm thinking I can re-use this but not sure how.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim R1 As Long, C1 As Long
Dim R2 As Long, C2 As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")

R1 = 3: C1 = 6
R2 = 3: C2 = C1 + 3

lastCol = 1

While lastCol < 256
    With ws
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R1, C1), .Cells(R2, C2))
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Rng.Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        C1 = C2 + 1
        C2 = C1 + 3
        lastCol = lastCol + 1
    End With
Wend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy a source range to as many groups of four columns as you specify with `NumberOfCopies`. You didn't say what range you are copying from, so I assumed G3:J3:

```
Sub CopyCols()
Dim rngSource As Excel.Range
Dim rngTarget As Excel.Range
Dim NumberOfCopies As Long

NumberOfCopies = 12
With ActiveSheet
    Set rngSource = .Range("G3:J3")
    Set rngTarget = .Range("K3").Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, NumberOfCopies * 4)
    rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngTarget
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ DougGlancy I believe you have half answered, I would like to copy F4:I4 and paste to J4:M4, with the "F" in the formula changing to a "J". and then repeating across the sheet to the last column, have I clarified? Sorry for any confusion

Comment: It works for me, at least I get your 2nd four formulas in K3:N3. The relative cell addresses will copy relatively, with the result you want. Did you try the code.

Comment: after modifying your code with my cell references it has indeed worked. Thank you very much, this is amazing!!!

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I could help. Trying to avoid loops is often instructive, and almost always faster!